# Can WCF open process in remote machine?

Tags: c#, wcf

Suppose I have WCF service running on my remote machine, this service get string from the client, on this remote machine I have a .NET executable which I want to execute.

Is it possible to execute this executable from machine hosting the WCF service?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to start the process on the WCF server, or on the client? If the former: of course, why not? What did you try, what happened? Whether it's advisable to do so is a different question.

Comment: I haven't try anything, i only want to know if it possible, i will do it now

Comment: Then try it. We are not your compilers or runtime. Or: why would you think it is not possible?

Comment: I guess i want to know before trying

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to know if a WCF service is able to run an external executable and perhaps pass a string parameter. If the interpretation is correct, then you should be able to accomplish with:

```
Process.Start("someApplication.exe")
```

The following link might help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx

Regards,